# Getting URL variable that is a string instead of a number

Tags: php, phpbb

I have a PHP script which I can query with a variable.

Here is the URL to do that:

```
ajax.php?var=3
```

And here is the bit (inside the PHP file) that grabs that number - it's a phpBB method that works similarly to GET()/POST():

```
$alink    = $request->variable('var', 1);
echo $alink;
```

[Here's the API section about this 'request' method if interested.](https://area51.phpbb.com/docs/code/3.1.x/phpbb/request/request.html#method_variable)

And this is what is outputted on the page when visited:

```
3
```

So that works fine. However, when I used a string instead of a number, all it returns is 0 :(

```
ajax.php?var=Apple
```

Returns:

```
0
```

When visited... so like, why is this and what do I have to do to get my request method to recognised the string? It works fine with a number, so why not a string too?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should ask that question to the developers of the API, or ask in their forum for help and explanation...

Comment: Seems $default is type strict, try `$request->variable('var', '')`, or `$request->variable('var', '1')` if you want a 1

Comment: I have: https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=641&t=2600046&p=15748631#p15748631

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone that did the trick!

Comment: np, I looked through the class, it has more in-depth comments https://php-download.com/package/phpbb/phpbb-core/file/request/request.php